# get data from table in URL with PHP

Tags: php, url, web-scraping

I am very new to PHP and I am trying to get product information(technical details table) from a website
https://www.amazon.nl/Lenovo-Ideapad-Full-HD-i7-10510U-GeForce/dp/B0851D4TYJ/ref=sr_1_2?__mk_nl_NL=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=laptop&qid=1604152028&sr=8-2

I have been looking at the $URL $_GET parse_url and other commands.
At the moment I am a little lost in how to proceed with this as I am finding a lot of information about getting information a website with either a command or with websrapping, I don't know if I have to make an array or not, or if it is better to do this with an API.

so all help is welcome and appreciated

Comment: If the site provides API, absolutely use those. Assume making a software that constantly asks for a web page can be seen as an attack on the site.

Comment: Technical details on websites that (try to) sell computer are rarely complete... (and you have to start again if they change the layout of their website)

Comment: And, a website from suppliers tend to have more, and completer data, see: https://psref.lenovo.com/Product/IdeaPad/ideapad_S54015IML?MT=81NG and https://psref.lenovo.com/Detail/IdeaPad/ideapad_S54015IML?M=81NG00BBMH (on this last page is a link to download the info in XLS-format)